# Apache ignite cache viewer like Redis Desktop Manager

Tags: c#, windows, caching, ignite, viewer

I am loving Apache Ignite particularly as distributed caching. However I have realised that the tooling is not as good.

I am looking for a simple desktop tool to be able to view and search the cache for values etc something similar to [Redis Deskop Manager](https://redisdesktop.com/)

I am in WINDOWS environment. My google searches has returned "DBeaver" which I have downloaded and configured but doesn't show my cache key values. The other one has been "Web Console" though this is a web based and I prefer some desktop thing - Not sure if I can install this locally?

Anything else around?

much appreciated.

Comment: Questions on professional server- or networking-related infrastructure administration are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve programming or programming tools. You may be able to get help on [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the closest you can get is LINQPad + .NET Thin Client.
Ignite NuGet package actually includes LINQPad sample to get first 5 items from every cache in cluster and display them, you can modify it to your needs.

This approach requires some coding, but is quite flexible with LINQ capabilities and rich API at your disposal, plus LINQPad data display features.

Sample code:

````
var cfg = new IgniteClientConfiguration { Host = "127.0.0.1" };
using (var client = Ignition.StartClient(cfg))
{
    // Create cache for demo purpose.
    var fooCache = client.GetOrCreateCache<int, object>("thin-client-test").WithKeepBinary<int, IBinaryObject>();
    fooCache[1] = client.GetBinary().GetBuilder("foo")
        .SetStringField("Name", "John")
        .SetTimestampField("Birthday", new DateTime(2001, 5, 15).ToUniversalTime())
        .Build();

    var cacheNames = client.GetCacheNames();
    "Diplaying first 5 items from each cache:".Dump();

    foreach (var name in cacheNames)
    {
        var cache = client.GetCache<object, object>(name).WithKeepBinary<object, object>();
        var items = cache.Query(new ScanQuery<object, object>()).Take(5)
            .ToDictionary(x => x.Key.ToString(), x => x.Value.ToString());

        items.Dump(name);
    }
}
```
````

Answer (score 0):

GridGain has [GUI tool](https://www.gridgain.com/products/software/enterprise-edition/management-tool) which allows you connect to your grid, peek into caches, as well as many more things.

It is a part of commercial offering, but will connect to Apache Ignite grids.

Comment: Its paid version and I even couldn't install it in windows 10 as its dependent in .net 3.5 that can't be install on windows 10. Its a shame that there is not a free tool!

Comment: @user1829319 It is a Java application so there's no way it will require any version of .net

Comment: I downloaded the professional version. Extracted the zip. Navigate to bin and ran the exe. Have you used it yourself? In additions I was looking for a freeware tool anyways.

Comment: @user1829319 I think it should be `ggvisor.bat` and not exe.